# Is there an Xcode version of "Override/Implement Method"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is one of my favorite eclipse features. Does it exist in Xcode? I'm getting tired of cutting and pasting from my header files in to my implementations.

Comment: It will autocomplete method names, but you have to type the `-` and the return type before it starts doing its stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I'm tired of typing -(void), finding myself typing it a lot. It would also work if there was an easy way to define code snippets, but it seems like that's a bit involved.

Comment: In Xcode 4.6 you don't have to type the return type (maybe has been that way for several versions, not sure).

Answer (score 35):

Just type "dash" then "space" and start typing the method name that you want to override. Now push Esc.
Example:

```
- tab
```

will prompt your to pick a method that overrides any of the TableViewDatasource / Delegate methods. Hit Return and it will automatically provide the return type too...

Here's a pic of what it looks like and notice that I did not provide the return type myself: [image]

Cheers...

Comment: This is complicated significantly by Objective-C naming. Your example there of `tableView:...` has many, many methods, and it's not easy to type a longer completion string. Fuzzy matching would go a long way -- if I could open an override dialog and type "tablewillBegin" and get the right method, that'd be great.

Answer (score 3):

With Swift, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> in the class body will bring up auto-complete for methods. Just start typing the method name.

If you're extending a class, XCode 10 doesn't seem to automatically insert `override` when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of task that a user script is useful for. I use this one I banged out in ruby.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby -w


dash="------------------------------------"
r=/(^.+);/ # find entire function definition
pr=/(\w+(:|;))/ #find named parameters to make selector style string
s=STDIN.read
s.each_line() do |l|
  m=l.match(r)
  if m
    n=l.match(/:/) 
    if n  #if the function as one or more parameters
     params=l.scan(/(\w+:)/) 
     puts m.captures[0] + "{\n\n}//"+dash + params.to_s + dash +"\n\n"
    else #method has no parameters
      puts m.captures[0]+ "{\n\n}//"+dash + m.captures[0] + dash +"\n\n"
    end 
  end
end
```

To use, select a header method definition, run the script, switch to implementation and paste. This one adds in my preferred method comments boiler plate so you can customized that as you wish.

Comment: Thanks TechZen. I'm looking for something even more streamlined, I think.

Comment: Actually, I'm working on something that will just take a single keystroke. It might be a couple of weeks though, I've got crawl under the hood in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html), it may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it could help in other things that you may like. I haven't used it extensively yet, but I got it as part of one of [MobileOrchard](http://www.mobileorchard.com)'s bundle.

Comment: +1 I was going to say this, although, personally, I just man up and do it the copy-paste way.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ODCompletionDictionary](http://www.obdev.at/products/completion-dictionary) plug-in for Xcode. It allows you to define expandable macros that are configurable with many options. It is an enormous time saver.